# How to refactor CSS based on HTML class

Tags: html, css

I have two CSSs.

The *first* one is this:

```
#breadcrumbs-cool a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  border-width: 1.5em 0 1.5em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc #ccc #ccc transparent;
  left: -1em;
}
```

Then the *next*

```
#breadcrumbs-cool a.disable::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  border-width: 1.5em 0 1.5em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eee #eee #eee transparent;
  left: -1em;
}
```

Notice that the only difference are class directive

```
a::before 
a.disable::before
```

And border color: `#ccc` versus `#eee`.
How can I refactor these two CSS?

Comment: remove everything but the border-color in the second rule

Comment: Just reuse the selectors and add in your desired styling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to keep this as is:

```
#breadcrumbs-two a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  border-width: 1.5em 0 1.5em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc #ccc #ccc transparent;
  left: -1em;
}
```

And then just overwrite the part you want to be specific when `disable` class is present

```
#breadcrumbs-two a.disable::before{
  border-color: #eee #eee #eee transparent;
}
```